# Angular Impulse equations for rotational dynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, torque

Consider a 3d rigid body at rest initially, assuming no net external forces acting on it. It is set in perpetual rotation along one of its principal axis. Now an angular impulse (which is a vector) acts on it in certain direction not parallel to its principal axis (the one parallel to axis of rotation).

we have two observations:

1. from newtons second law of motion analogous on rotational dynamics, 
   we have $\mathbf \tau = \frac{\text d\mathbf L}{\text dt}$, or $\int \mathbf\tau\ \text dt = \Delta\mathbf L$   ($\mathbf\tau$, $\mathbf L$ are torque and angular momentum 
   vectors)
2. finally after the angular impulse acts on it the body still remains in 
   perpetual rotation about some principal axes.

How would you find the new axis of rotation ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91847/discussion-on-question-by-programmer-angular-impulse-equations-for-rotational-dy).